# Angular Material dialog popup shows in the bottom of page instead of popupping

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm creating Angular Material dialog popup but instead of popupping the component shows in the bottom.

Component.ts

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

openDialog(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
    width: '250px'
    
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('The dialog was closed');
  });
}
```

With imports:

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Pick one</button>
```

app.module

```
..
import {MatDialogModule, MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DialogComponentComponent } from './dialog-component/dialog-component.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    Component,
    DialogComponent
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false}}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [DialogComponentComponent]
})
```

Result the component shows in the bottom of the page instead of popup:
[image]

Comment: i guess you messed up with angular stylesheet , can you paste the ```angular.json``` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you import angular materail style in angular.json

```
 "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/your-project",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
        // make sure you import this style from angular material
        "styles": ["./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css","src/styles.scss"],
        "scripts": []
      },
```

Comment: Thank you 
./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css
is missed on my project

Comment: glad that helped